# Is this recursive function always surjective?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

> Let $S:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}^+$ satisfy
> $$
> \left\{
> \begin{aligned} 
> S(n) &= S(A^n \bmod n) + S(B^n \bmod n) \\
> S(0) &= 1
> \end{aligned}
> \right.
> $$

My question is, is this function always surjective for all values of $A, B \geq 2$ with $A \neq B$?

(When $A$'s and $B$'s set of prime factor are completely the same, odd numbers are unobtainable. Is this the only case where surjectivity fails?)